# Spinner inside button tag

Tags: javascript, spinner

I just found some example code on jsbin website.

That button works perfectly, but without any form action.

What could I do about that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function abc(this1)
{
  this1.disabled=true; 
  this1.innerHTML='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> Sending Love&#8230;';

}
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="dfdsfs.php" method=post>
  <button  type="submit" id="id1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abc(this);" > Send Love</button>
  
  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What is not working? What do you want to do?

Comment: What is it that you want this button to perform?

Comment: Button is static at the moment. I need it to use it like tpical submit button.

Comment: I need send some variables to .php file but now nothing happpening

Comment: `onclick` and `type="submit"` don't work very well together. Can't you use `onsubmit` on your form instead?

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it more readable. But I agree to the other comments: your question is too broad. You see, this community is not a place where you drop some code you found somewhere, to then give vague requirements and ask others to improve stuff. Learning to programming works differently: *you* have to do a ton of research. You make experiments, you try this, you try that. In other words: A) read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me

Comment: and then B) improve your question.